# record syntax on a GADT-style data type declaration issue

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to make the following compile ([record syntax on a GADT-style](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/6.6/docs/html/users_guide/gadt.html)) :

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE NamedFieldPuns #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DuplicateRecordFields #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
module Gsd.CLI.Steps where

import System.Console.Byline
import Data.Text

import Gsd.Clients
import Gsd.Read.Workspace
import Gsd.Read.Goal

type ErrorDescription = String
type WorkOnWorkspacesStepHandle = Clients -> Byline IO ()
type WorkOnAWorkspaceStepHandle = Clients -> Workspace ->  WorkOnWorkspacesStepHandle -> Byline IO ()
type WorkOnAGoalStepHandle      = Clients -> Workspace -> Goal ->  WorkOnAWorkspaceStepHandle -> WorkOnWorkspacesStepHandle -> Byline IO ()



data StepName = WorkOnWorkspaces | WorkOnAWorkspace | WorkOnAGoal

data Step a  where
  WorkOnWorkspacesStep  { workOnWorkspaces:: WorkOnWorkspacesStepHandle, clients::Clients } :: Step WorkOnWorkspaces
  WorkOnAWorkspaceStep  { workOnWorkspace::  WorkOnAWorkspaceStepHandle, clients::Clients, workspace::Workspace , workOnWorkspaces:: WorkOnWorkspacesStepHandle} ::  Step WorkOnAWorkspace
  WorkOnAGoalStep       { workOnAGoal ::     WorkOnAGoalStepHandle,      clients::Clients, workspace::Workspace,  goal::Goal , workOnWorkspace::  WorkOnAWorkspaceStepHandle, workOnWorkspaces:: WorkOnWorkspacesStepHandle} :: Step WorkOnAGoal
```

the compiler doesn't like the `data Step a` syntax I have used

```
/Users/nhenin/dev/gsdFlow/src/Gsd/CLI/Steps.hs:25:25: error: parse error on input ‘{’
   |
25 |   WorkOnWorkspacesStep  { workOnWorkspaces:: WorkOnWorkspacesStepHandle, clients::Clients } :: Step WorkOnWorkspaces
   |                         ^

                    ^
```

I'm following this example :

```
  data Term a where
      Lit    { val  :: Int }      :: Term Int
      Succ   { num  :: Term Int } :: Term Int
      Pred   { num  :: Term Int } :: Term Int
      IsZero { arg  :: Term Int } :: Term Bool  
      Pair   { arg1 :: Term a
             , arg2 :: Term b
             }                    :: Term (a,b)
      If     { cnd  :: Term Bool
             , tru  :: Term a
             , fls  :: Term a
             }                    :: Term a
```

Which does not compile as well surprisingly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax is (crazy):

```
data Foo a where
  Bar :: { fd1 :: T1, fd2 :: T2 } -> Foo b
  --- etc.
```

So in this case you might want:

```
data Step a  where
  WorkOnWorkspacesStep ::
    { workOnWorkspaces:: WorkOnWorkspacesStepHandle
    , clients::Clients } ->
    Step WorkOnWorkspaces
  WorkOnAWorkspaceStep ::
    { workOnWorkspace::  WorkOnAWorkspaceStepHandle
    , clients::Clients
    , workspace::Workspace
    , workOnWorkspaces:: WorkOnWorkspacesStepHandle } ->
    Step WorkOnAWorkspace
  WorkOnAGoalStep ::
    { workOnAGoal ::     WorkOnAGoalStepHandle
    , clients::Clients
    , workspace::Workspace
    , goal::Goal
    , workOnWorkspace:: WorkOnAWorkspaceStepHandle
    , workOnWorkspaces:: WorkOnWorkspacesStepHandle } ->
    Step WorkOnAGoal
```

For reference, see the [GHC user guide](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#generalised-algebraic-data-types-gadts) (near the bottom of the linked section).

EDIT: Unfortunately, this appears to not be actually legal

> However, for GADTs there is the following additional constraint: every constructor that has a field f must have the same result type (modulo alpha conversion)

Comment: I was looking to an older version of ghc ! that's why I had issues ....

Comment: Actually this doesn't work because of the constraint on the types of constructors with the same fields.